# Laravel 4: Route package

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am trying to put routes into a package and I am able to run the route in the package after reading this: http://laravel.com/docs/packages#package-routing

Example working route in package:

```
Route::get('pack', function()
{
    return 'It works!!!';
});
```

Now I am able to get the return from route properly and display 'It works!!!!' on the webpage. However, how can I set the route to display a file from the package? I was trying with `return View::make('test');` but it didn't works.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the file in the `src/views` folder and load it like this:

```
\View::make('packageName::test');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it says: `No hint path defined for [MyPackage]`. How can I define the path?

Comment: Did you remember to replace `packageName` with the name of your package? Did you call `$this->package()` on your service provider? Did you include your service provider on `app/config/app.php`?

Comment: Yes, I does include service provider in `app/config/app.php`, added `$this->package('MyVender/MyPackage');` and `View::addNamespace('MyPackage', __DIR__.'/../../Views');` in boot function on MyPackageServiceProvider.php. But now, I receive `Class 'MyVender\MyPackage\View' not found` error.

Comment: `\View`. Or simply do `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;`.

Comment: I don't get what you try to say. Anyway, do you see anything I done wrong from my previous comment?

Comment: You need to do `\View::addNamespace(...)`. Notice the backslash at the beginning.

Comment: Just one question, Rapheal. Why `\View`? When I look around all tutorials and guide, they all didn't show or even mention about backslash in front of View. Is it a proper way of doing? Thanks.

Comment: The backslash means you're accessing the root namespace. Most tutorials don't mention it because, while inside your regular app, meaning models, controllers, and all, you are in fact in the root namespace. When you start a package, though, you leave that.

Comment: Just complementing: so, say your package namespace is `MyVendor/MyPackage`. When you call `View::make()`, you're actually trying to access `MyVendor/MyPackage/View` class. The backslash sends you back to the root namespace.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. Now, I am better understanding about it. :)